# Why my function doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, function, dom

I have a link in to the title attribute in a div like this -

```
<div class="tooltip" title="<a onclick='ersal();'>send</a>"><img src="<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>" width="70" height="70"  /></div>
```

and I have a function in jquery that name is `ersal()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function ersal(){
          alert("Clicked!");
    };
    });
</script>
```

but when I click to link send my function doesn't work why?

Comment: You can't bind the click event to an attribute, only an element, and you can't have HTML in the title attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For handling hover event, you should use this code:

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="tooltip" title="Click here">
  <img src="<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>" width="70" height="70"  />
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var c = $(document);
 c.on("mouseenter",".tooltip",function(){ alert("Clicked!"); });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML code should be like this-

```
<div class="tooltip" title="Click here" onclick='ersal()'>
  <img src="<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>" width="70" height="70"  />
</div>
```

For handling click event, you should use `onclick` property and the value for it can be javascript code or any javascript function call. The syntax can be given like this -

```
<element onclick="Somejavascriptcode">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an url in the title attribute.

Try like that, for example :

```
<a id="my-link" class="tooltip" href="#" title="Link to Image">
  <img src="<?php echo 'admin/'.$item['img'] ?>" width="70" height="70" />
</a>
```

And your `jQuery` should be :

```
$('#my-link').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Or :

```
$('#my-link').click(function(){
    ersal();
});

function ersal(){
    alert('clicked');
}
```